# Session timeout different just for one variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In **cookies** we can use the `Expires` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires%28VS.80%29.aspx) to define the expiration date.

In .Net 4.0 (MVC) is it possible to define a **session** timeout different just for one variable?

I am really not a big fan of having something similar to:

```
session["VariableCreatedOn"] = DateTime.Now()
session["VariableValue"] = xxx
```

And then try to verify if the `VariableCreatedOn` is older than XYZ.

By default is there a solution for this?

Comment: you can chage session timeout but for whole session..and its stored in serialized format.. you can read more about session http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way, BUT you can achieve it very simple:

```
Session[name] = value;

//now add a cleanup task that will run after the specified interval
Task.Delay(expireAfter).ContinueWith((task) => {
    Session.Remove(name);
});
```

I wrapped this into a very handy "session extender" class [here](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/196-aspnet-session-caching-expiring-values/) use it like this:

```
//store and expire after 5 minutes
Session.AddWithTimeout("key", "value", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

PS. If you're still using an old .NET version (no async code, no tasks) you'll find a compatible version under the link there too.

Comment: Thanks :) I will check your blog.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in MVC 5. `Session` is `null` once the `Delay` elapses. So it would seem that a closure doesn't capture `Session`. Am I missing something?  ** edit: Assigning `Session` to a local variable seems to rectify.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to directly have one session variable expire while the rest of the session lives on, or vice versa.

Rather than have to check whether the value has expired all over the place, though, you could wrap this logic in a custom class and store an object of that class in the session (instead of storing the value and the expiry-date or creation-date as two separate values).

It would work similarly to nullable value types, in that you'd have a Value property on that class, and the getter for that property would either return a value or return null depending on the value of an internal CreationDate property.

Untested code follows; adapt as per your specific needs.

```
public class ExpiringSessionValue<T>
{
    private T _value;
    private DateTime _created = DateTime.Now;

    public ExpiringSessionValue(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_created >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
                return _value;
            else
                return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `_created` you could store the precalculated "expiry" date. That will save a few nanoseconds for the repeated `AddMinutes`, if you get the Value often.